# changing forward slash key to return key

Tags: keyboard, keybindings

I've just bought a new Macbook Air and the keyboard is an International English keyboard instead of an English keyboard.

This means that the return key is too far away. Normally the return key is where the forward slash key is and the forward slash key is above the return key. 
I have small hands and to use the return key in its current location I have to move my hands to the left.

Ditto there's a key between the z key and the shift key, a squiggly line and accent underneath it, which isn't there in the standard keyboard I'm used to. 
I've downloaded Ukulele but it doesn't seem to be able to change the return key. Apple said the same thing. I can change all the other keys, but not the return and shirt keys, the very two I need to change.

Any ideas anyone?

Comment: Shirt key = Shift key?

Comment: If you bought your new Macbook Air from Apple then you could return it to Apple under their "no quibble, full refund" returns policy.  Sorry, I realise this is not answering the keyboard question you asked, but….

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/) with a private.xml such as the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <item>
    <name>Changing forward slash key with return key</name>
    <identifier>private.slashreturn</identifier>
    <autogen>
      __KeyToKey__
      KeyCode::SLASH,
      KeyCode::RETURN
    </autogen>
  </item>
  <item>
    <name>Changing tilde key with left shift</name>
    <identifier>private.tildeleftshift</identifier>
    <autogen>
      __KeyToKey__
      KeyCode::BACKQUOTE,
      KeyCode::SHIFT_L
    </autogen>
  </item>
</root>
```